# ListFragment sometimes skips code in onLoadFinished() method of Loader

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, android-loader

I have a `ListFragment` which fetches data from the net using a `Loader`. I use a new instance of this `ListFragment` in every page of my `ViewPager`. It works perfectly, but when I use `TabLayout` or moves pages quickly, the `Fragment` keeps loading and does not display the data in the `ListView`.

When I checked using log messages, I found that the `ListFragment` skips some lines of code in the `onLoadFinished()` method. It does not make the `ProgressBar` invisible. It does add items to `Adapter`, but it is not being displayed in the `ListView`. This problem also happens in the first page of the `ViewPager`.

Is there any specific rule to be followed when using `ListFragment`s in a `ViewPager`?

Here is the `ListFragment` class. If you look at the `onLoadFinished()` method, you can see the lines causing problem:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<GameNews>> {

    public static ListViewFragment newInstance(String url) {
        Log.d("ListViewFragment", "newInstance created");
        ListViewFragment f = new ListViewFragment();

        // Supply url input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("url", url);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    List<GameNews> TotalNews;
    ListView gameListView;
    LinearLayout emptyView;
    Button retryButton;
    ListAdapter adapter ;
    private View progressBar;
    final private int game_loader = 0;
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    String mUrlString;
    int index;

    //LIFE CYCLE OF FRAGMENT
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUrlString = getArguments().getString("url");
        urls.add(mUrlString);
        TotalNews = new ArrayList<GameNews>();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);

        ArrayList<GameNews> gameList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), gameList);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        emptyView = (LinearLayout)
            view.findViewById(R.id.no_internet_view);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        retryButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.retry_button);
        gameListView = getListView();
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //If connected to net start the loader
        if (isConnected()) {
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(game_loader,
                                                                  null,
                                                                  ListViewFragment.this);
        }
    }

    //OVERRIDED METHODS OF LOADERMANAGER
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<GameNews>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        AdManager manager =  new AdManager(getActivity());
        return new FragmentLoader(getActivity(), urls, 1000);

    }

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM PLEASE FOCUS INSIDE THIS METHOD
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<GameNews>> loader, List<GameNews> games) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //This line of code is not executed
        adapter.clear();
        TotalNews.addAll(games);
        adapter.addAll(games);//And the listView is not populated
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<GameNews>> loader) {
        adapter.clear();
    }

    //REUSABLE METHODS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Method checks if there is internet
    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not know how to make a question easily readable.Thanks for advise .I will try it now sir.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it works great now.I am so happy that i dont how to express my gratitude towards.

Comment: If you write this as an answer I will accept it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Fragment` class is using the `Activity`'s `LoaderManager`:

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(...);
```

And each instance is using the same ID in its `restartLoader()` call:

```
final private int game_loader = 0;
```

This means that each `Fragment` instance was using and restarting the same `Loader` over and over again, leading to the weird behavior you observed.

The solution is quite simple: use `Fragment`'s local `LoaderManager`, instead of the `Activity`'s.

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(...);
```

With this, you don't need to worry about changing the ID in each instance, since `Loader`s are unique to their `Fragment`, and the `Loader` will be properly handled over the `Fragment`'s lifetime, which would likely not have been the case when using the `Activity`'s `LoaderManager`.